# Assigning values from one polygon to second polygon if located within first using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, fields-attributes

I have two layers of polygons. I would like to know if there is a way to assign a value from
a polygon in the first layer to any polygons from the second layer that fall within that polygon?

Comment: the attribute mapping tool works nicely if there are not too many that you want to automate it. Edit your original question with more info (how many polygons/ type of solution).

Comment: Spatial Join answer sounds like it will fit the bill, however other options include Identity, Intersect and Union depending on what you want to do with polygons that partially overlap or are outside. Can you draw a picture of an example of what you want to do with polygons within, part overlapping and outside the *from* polygons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000q000000) geoprocessing tool will do what you're looking for.

With the tool parameters something like this

- Target Features: polygon dataset to which you wish to join attributes.
- Join Features: polygon dataset from which the attributes will be transferred IF they meet the Match Option (Spatial Relationship).
- Output Feature Class: feature class to which the result of the operation will be written.
- Match Option: WITHIN